# How to change a popover's appearance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there anyway of changing the appearance of a popover?  I am interested in changing the border to be lighter perhaps more transparent then black

Comment: I suggest you to design your own popover because it is easy for implementation. And even you can used different custom animations.

Comment: Yep - its just much easier using the popover.

Comment: @Prcela - Any suggestions on where to start for building your own popover? Any sites or resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so...I have been scouring the internet trying to solve the same problem. It looks like for right now, black is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample how to display simple pop-up that will appear animated and disappear animated after few seconds. Header file:

```
@interface ViewPopup : UIView 
{
  IBOutlet UILabel *m_lblMessage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *m_lblMessage;
- (void) showFromView: (UIView*)viewParent;
```

And implementation part:

```
@implementation ViewPopup
@synthesize m_lblMessage;
- (void) showFromView: (UIView*)viewParent
{
  [viewParent addSubview:self];
  [self setCenter: CGPointMake(viewParent.frame.size.width/2, -self.frame.size.height/2)];
  [UIView beginAnimations: @"ShowPopup" context: nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
  [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
  [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(onAppeared)];
  self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.frame.size.height+40);
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void) onAppeared
{
  [self performSelector: @selector(hide) withObject: nil afterDelay: 3];
}
- (void) hide
{
  [UIView beginAnimations: @"HidePopup" context: nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
  [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
  [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
  self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)dealloc 
{
  [m_lblMessage release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Invocation from any view and from any place in code:

```
ViewPopup *viewPopup = (ViewPopup*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] getViewFromNib: @"ViewPopup" class: [ViewPopup class] owner: nil];
viewPopup.m_lblMessage.text = @"Hello";
[viewPopup showFromView: someView];
```

Note that popup graphics is loaded from the ViewPopup.xib file. It has only some graphics and text label.